# Touch screen hide cursor

Tags: windows, winapi, cursor, touch, show-hide

I have an existing windows XP based application that has 2 screens (and currently 2 PCs, one hosting each screen).  One is a touch screen and the other a normal mouse driven screen.  The touch screen is used for quick user actions e.g. touch for an action to be triggered.  The application uses the mouse pointer within the non-touch application window to determine where to carry out the action.  I want to get rid of the the PC hosting the touch screen, and just have a touch screen hosted on one PC (dual screen).  However, if I do this is there any way to stop the cursor moving to the touch screen?  I don't think I have focus issues because I can use WS_EX_NOACTIVATE within the touch screen application (the touch screen application only has to respond to touch events).

I have seen some internet posts saying that the cursor can be hidden via the touch panel configuration (if supported), but does anyone know whether these is windows OS support for this?  I have freedom to move to Windows 7 if this provides the answer.  I also don't particularly want to capture the events at the device level (before reaching the OS).

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP doesn't have native support for touch screens (because at the time it was written there were almost no touch devices), so the touch events that come from a touch screen are treated as mouse events on Windows XP. I don't think there is any way to make a difference between a touch and a mouse click in Windows XP (at application level after reaching OS, not at device level before reaching OS).

Windows 7 on the other hand introduced real support for touch. Whenever a touch event happens, you get a [WM_TOUCH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317341%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message which is very easy to use and, of course, has nothing to do with the mouse.

In conclusion, I think you should upgrade to Windows 7 as it has way better support for touch input. If you decide to go with the Win7 WM_TOUCH, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371581%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'s another article that should be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, it is the mouse cursor that I am primarily concerned with i.e. I don't want the mouse cursor to jump from my non-touch screen application to the touch screen when the user triggers the touch event.

Comment: The WM_TOUCH will not move your mouse cursor, it doesn't affect the mouse at all. It is simply another kind of input device with other types of messages.

Comment: Have eventually tried this out on Windows 7 and it doesn't work on the panel I have.  The mouse cursor still jumps to the touch screen.  Have  seen some postings about windows 7 control panel control but these don't seem to be available with my device.

Comment: @Nigel: Andrei's description is somewhat inaccurate. Even though Windows 7 introduced native touch support, the system still generates mouse messages (to support legacy applications without dedicated touch support). While you can [filter out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd693088.aspx) generated messages, the mouse cursor still gets moved. You'd probably have to constantly store the mouse cursor position, hide the cursor on touch input, and restore the mouse position on genuine mouse input.